# How to get Disclaimer on back side of every page I print in Jasper iReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using iReports 5.6.0 and I have to print a Disclaimer for a company on back side of their Invoice. The main report is basically divided into 3 Subreports:

1st is for the Logo (Company Name and their information)

2nd is INVOICE TO (It's for the customer who gets billed)

3rd is Last Page Footer (shows total calculation)

In between 2nd n 3rd Subreports there is the Table in 1st Detail Band which lists the products with their price.

The problem is, the table has many entries which makes the table extend into the next page and so on. I need the disclaimer to be printed in between each page of those tables as well.

I have tried putting the disclaimer in a another detail band right after the 1st Detail Band (in which the table resides) and used PrintWhenExpression but the Disclaimer is printed after the whole table has printed.

Other thing i tried is that I put the disclaimer inside the table below the table row. But the disclaimer can only reside in one of the column of the table (I have 3 columns in the table). I need to print the disclaimer in the whole page with full width (not the width of 1 column of table).

Please help! Below is the my source code in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JasperMemo_Print_WithImages" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="980" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="75f92902-a586-4cdc-bb02-dd1a2a8f5189">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.7513148009015809"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="213"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="false"/>
    <subDataset name="DataSetReport" uuid="fc85dfe6-1cd0-47a6-8fe8-4b1e953bbcba">
        <parameter name="ORDERBY" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="IMGDIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="MEMOID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
          <QUERY>
        </queryString>
        <field name="dummyNo." class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="r" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="line1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="line2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="line3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="memoId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="issueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="PO_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="salesperson" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SHIPVIA" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="jwl_item" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="qty" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="item" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="freight" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="jwlImage" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="price_per_ct" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="totalPrice" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="total" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="memo_total" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="sub_total" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="state" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="phone" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="add2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="add3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fax" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="cell" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="Message" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="add1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shipTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpstate" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpphone" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpadd2" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpadd3" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpfax" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="shpadd1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\backupServer\\Superior\\PrintWithImage\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ORDERBY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="IMGDIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="MEMOID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="1" class="java.lang.Long">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="288" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="180" uuid="95362b59-e8b3-406d-a043-3252ac7cb3fb"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:JasperMemo_Print_WithImages_subreport1.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="555" height="108" uuid="888548a5-f49f-4b1d-831a-c6f0f7ae7cc0"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMOID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMOID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:JasperMemo_Print_WithImages_subreport3.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="14f930cc-833f-4766-a233-b6363b285808"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DataSetReport" uuid="1bfe5313-a62c-41b7-b7b6-c31326712076">
                        <datasetParameter name="ORDERBY">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ORDERBY}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="IMGDIR">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMGDIR}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="MEMOID">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMOID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="5" uuid="a72c408a-cadd-4696-b870-735251a1e1fc">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="17" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter height="5" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:columnFooter>
                        <jr:detailCell height="67" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="107" uuid="00601a34-01f3-4184-814d-1abf08dd9a1c">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="17" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="1" y="0" width="106" height="17" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#999999" uuid="9f3f2651-f198-445f-8968-9fe84838567c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Item]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter height="5" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:columnFooter>
                        <jr:detailCell height="67" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="55" y="0" width="51" height="42" uuid="3c9fe3f8-108f-4c6f-909f-13cc7e3233f0"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[IF($F{jwl_item}!='',$F{jwl_item},$F{item})]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <image onErrorType="Blank">
                                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="55" height="42" uuid="f57348f9-53ac-478c-a3c7-92016b617b02"/>
                                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{jwlImage}]]></imageExpression>
                            </image>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="338" uuid="1f52660d-f50f-4bf8-872c-1759819ea1cb">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="17" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="338" height="17" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#999999" uuid="868ee437-e0b6-4ef8-ab46-769abe481c9b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="11"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter height="5" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:columnFooter>
                        <jr:detailCell height="67" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="338" height="14" uuid="2c96054a-b2a1-4cef-9184-ecf8ff5f07da"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{line1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="14" width="338" height="14" uuid="ad24e9a2-29fd-4aea-a599-486732a4f076"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{line2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="28" width="338" height="14" uuid="e64af041-61be-4473-97d9-4ec426a3da2c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{line3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="26235dfe-1cf3-4408-81ba-45cb348fb267">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="17" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="17" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#999999" uuid="1b3e9144-219a-477c-8f6c-71acf932b170"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total Price  ]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter height="5" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                        </jr:columnFooter>
                        <jr:detailCell height="67" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <topPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <leftPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#999999"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineColor="#999999"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="$#,##0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="42" uuid="fbf5f574-a8e5-4fbf-a145-4717ac3aa516"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="136">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="136" uuid="835dcc6c-bc58-440f-adae-7a3f4b55a2e8"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMOID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMOID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:JasperMemo_Print_WithImages_subreport4.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="792" splitType="Prevent">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="26" y="75" width="529" height="316" uuid="c2a2bf08-f453-4d19-a931-69ee2067302a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" leftIndent="35" rightIndent="35"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><DISCLAIMER FOR THE LAST PAGE></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="26" y="391" width="529" height="69" uuid="e4b804a0-616a-40b5-aafd-9b449c1e2fbf"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" leftIndent="35" rightIndent="35"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><DISCLAIMER FOR THE LAST PAGE></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="26" y="460" width="529" height="69" uuid="7dbc6393-2b05-4f60-905a-fcd1ba4c8f59"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" leftIndent="35" rightIndent="35"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><DISCLAIMER FOR THE LAST PAGE></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="26" y="529" width="529" height="177" uuid="f3c20864-0e4a-417c-bf15-6951576413ff"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" leftIndent="35" rightIndent="35"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><DISCLAIMER FOR THE LAST PAGE></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
    <noData>
        <band/>
    </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: are you using java to compile and export/view the report?, hence is a solution in java a viable solution?

Comment: There is no need to compile as the I use iReports Designer. It uses JRXML file to be uploaded on TIBCO Jasper Server which is then downloaded in .PDF format for printing.